# parse_ini_file doesn't work inside a class

Tags: php, ini

I've created a simple .ini file under `projectRoot/conf/` with the below inside:

```
[db]
name="db_name"
usr="someone"
pass="a_definitely_secure_pass"
host="some_host"
```

If I call this in `projectRoot/index.php` like so:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/site.ini', true);
echo '<pre>'. print_r($ini,1) .'</pre>';
```

Then I get my array:

```
Array
(
    [db] => Array
        (
            [name] => db_name
            [usr] => someone
            [pass] => a_definitely_secure_pass
            [host] => some_host
        )
)
```

However, if I try to do this with classes, then I get a NULL output. Here is my base controller class:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Core;

    class Controller
    {
        protected $ini;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->ini = false;

            if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/site.ini')) {
                $this->ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/site.ini', true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which I extend with a generic (minified) DB class:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Core;

    class Connection extends Controller
    {
        protected $conn;
        protected $qry;
        protected $stmt;

        public function __construct()
        {
            var_dump($this->ini); # this shows as NULL

            # this all fatal error's as it can't seem to parse the ini file correctly
            $this->conn = new \PDO(
                'mysql:host='. $this->ini['db']['host'] .';dbname='. $this->ini['db']['name'],
                $this->ini['db']['usr'],
                $this->ini['db']['pass']
            );

            $this->stmt = false;
            $this->qry = '';

            parent::__construct();
        }

        # etc
```

Which in turn, gets called on my `index.php` page for now (along with the test to parse the file):

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/vendor/autoload.php';

    # this works
    $ini = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/site.ini', true);
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($ini,1) .'</pre>';

    # trying to do it like this causes the fatal error
    $conn = new \App\Core\Connection();

    $conn->select(['*'], 'orders')
        ->join('order_items', 'order_id', 'orders', 'order_id', 1)
        ->where('total', 'lt')
        ->execute([5]);

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($conn->fetchAll(), 1) .'</pre>';
```

Which makes me think, maybe there's a scope issue here - but changing it from a `protected` var to `public` had no effect.

Why can't I set/get my .ini conf values using a class?

Comment: Use the [global namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) -> `$this->ini = \parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/conf/site.ini', true);`

Comment: @RaymondNijland same issue I'm afraid :/ plus, I thought global namespacing was for calling classes outside the current namespace? o.O

Comment: i mean then within the `namespace App\Core;` class..

Comment: In your Connection class - would it help if you called `parent::__construct();` at the start of the constructor?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah that's where I did it^^

Comment: `file_exists` also needs to be `\file_exists`  ...

Comment: @NigelRen bingo that was it - bad `parent::__construct()` placement on my part

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't think the global namespace is used like that as much anymore - all works without the slashes, was a case of calling `parent::__construct()` first :S

Comment: @NigelRen legend - literally about to ping asking for a dupe :p ty

Comment: The dupe isn't exactly the issue, but it sort of covers it.

Comment: *"I don't think the global namespace is used like that as much anymore - all works without the slashes"* Uhm ok still the PHP manual says it important to use it like that even for PHP7,, Anyhow didn't you got notices/warnings ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland weird, first time I've seen someone advocate it's usage (aside from returning to global namespacing within a namespace) - but may just be my experience thus far. I got a PDO fatal error but no other

Comment: @NigelRen naah the second answer sums it up well - it's because the child __construct is effectively "overwriting" it's parent, you need to call the parent construct to get access to whatever goes on inside it - which I guess makes sense, I just chose to call it last instead of before I needed everything xD

Comment: well the goal of those namespaces en global namespaces it to prevent name collisions using `\file_exists` and `\parse_ini_file` always makes sure it does not give a collision with a other namespace that also might have defined a custom file_exists or a parse_ini_file  function in a class

Comment: @RaymondNijland ahh from that perspective it makes sense - I'd hope that people wouldn't call their functions the same as native ones - but you can't stop people haha ty^ :)

Comment: *" I'd hope that people wouldn't call their functions the same as native ones - but you can't stop people haha ty^ :) –"* i would call them fileExists() and parseIniFile() anyhow no you can't stop it indeed  ...